# Is there a notion of 'distance' between coordinate frames?

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, metric-spaces

Say I have some coordinate system $X$ and another coordinate system $Y$ each covering the whole of Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^3$. And I have a mapping between the two $X=f(Y)$. ($f$ is a vector function $f:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$. ) If $f$ is a simple translation one could define the 'distance' between the coordinate systems as the length of this translation.

Now if $f$ is a more complicated function such as a diffeomorphism, is there still some kind of standard notion of distance? The three main properties it should have are:

- If $f$ is the identity $f(X)=X$ the distance would be zero (because X and Y would be the same)
- If $f$ is a translation $f(X)=X+P$ the distance would be |P|
- The 'distance' for the transform $f$ would be the same as that for $f^{-1}$ (because the 'distance' between $X$ and $Y$ should be the same as the 'distance' between $Y$ and $X$).

The distance would be some functional of $f$,  $d=F[f]$ what would $F$ be?

To put it another way, if we imagine a picture drawn in the first coordinate system, the 'distance' would somehow tell us how different the picture would be after a transform by $f$. But also if the picture is just a single point it would tell us how far that point has moved.

My first guess was that provided $f$ tends towards the identity function as $|x|\rightarrow \infty$:

$$ F[f] = \int | f(x) - f^{-1}(x) | dx^3$$

but that looks pretty strange!

Edit: From comment below it was suggested:

$$ F[f] = \int | f(x) - x | dx^3$$

I can sort of see visually why that might satisfy the conditions since a reflection in the line $y=x$ gives the inverse function but I can't prove it algebraically. (I substitute in $x=f^{-1}(y)$ to change variables I get a non-trivial measure.)

- A third desirable condition might be that the distance for $f(f(x))$ would be twice that for $f(x)$. But that might be asking too much!

Edit: Another idea I had was this one:

$$F[f]^2 = \int (f(x)-x)^2 \det \left(\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x} \right)^{1/2}dx^3$$

but not sure if the determinant is necessary?

Comment: Your expression is almost always divergent, but why not try $\lim\sup_{V\to\mathbb R^3}\frac1{\mathrm{Vol}(V)}\int_V|f(x)-x|d^3x$. It even satisfies the triangle inequality, but may be infinite.

Comment: But I think that will give a different distance depending on whether you are going from X to Y or from Y to X which would use the inverse function. But maybe distance in this case is not symmetric?

Comment: Actually thinking about it, that might work.  I just need to check its invariant under $f\rightarrow f^{-1}$. It would be in one dimension at least...

Comment: Can you explain how it satisfies the triangle inequality?

Comment: Are you just throwing ideas? Your last update, for instance, clearly violates  the translation property you proposed.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it might help. Does the last one not work? f(x)=x+P. So f(x)-x = P. $\partial f(x) = 1$. So $F[f]\propto P$?

Comment: The last one I was trying to get it so it is invariant under $f\rightarrow f^{-1}$

Comment: Oh, that's $(F[f])^2$? Then I take back what I said.

Comment: I found a better one that actually converges but its quite complicated: $$F[f]^2 = \int e^{-(x-y).(f(x)-f(y))} (f(x)-x).(f(y)-y)\det \left(\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x} \right)^{1/2}\det \left(\frac{\partial f(y)}{\partial y} \right)^{1/2}dx^3 dy^3$$

Comment: actually no, it doesn't converge :(